# How to round a container in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a design to fulfill, which is an icon with a white background, which must be round.
I have tried many possible ways but I have not been able to achieve that.

I attach the images and code of what I have done.

My current design:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

My code:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.White)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Outlined.StarOutline,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .padding(10.dp),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The order of the modifiers matters](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters), for what you are trying to achieve the composable should be first clipped and then apply that white background:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50))
        .background(Color.White)
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Outlined.StarOutline,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .padding(10.dp),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

I've also set the RoundedCornerShape to 50% so that it's circular as in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Modifier.background/shadow/border takes shape params. If you don't want to clip the shape itself, for instance to limit clickable area, you can use `Modifier.background(color, shape)` too.

[How to give a Box a CircleShaped stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089220/how-to-give-a-box-a-circleshaped-stroke/73091667#73091667)

Also there is a pre-defined `CircleShape`.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color.White, shape = CircleShape)
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Outlined.StarOutline,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .padding(10.dp),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```